# Image not appearing using django oscar default settings

Tags: django-oscar

I've been following the instructions on this site.

https://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.0/internals/getting_started.html

The site is up and running locally, but the image for the test product I have created isn't appearing.

Any ideas what I am missing?

[image]

## Settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for frobshop project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.2.12.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/
"""

from oscar.defaults import *
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-ch_02veha_%n@0gem8o&n*#mpocm=p!u)ibzx%s3i-%y+6lzs3'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.flatpages',

    'oscar.config.Shop',
    'oscar.apps.analytics.apps.AnalyticsConfig',
    'oscar.apps.checkout.apps.CheckoutConfig',
    'oscar.apps.address.apps.AddressConfig',
    'oscar.apps.shipping.apps.ShippingConfig',
    'oscar.apps.catalogue.apps.CatalogueConfig',
    'oscar.apps.catalogue.reviews.apps.CatalogueReviewsConfig',
    'oscar.apps.communication.apps.CommunicationConfig',
    'oscar.apps.partner.apps.PartnerConfig',
    'oscar.apps.basket.apps.BasketConfig',
    'oscar.apps.payment.apps.PaymentConfig',
    'oscar.apps.offer.apps.OfferConfig',
    'oscar.apps.order.apps.OrderConfig',
    'oscar.apps.customer.apps.CustomerConfig',
    'oscar.apps.search.apps.SearchConfig',
    'oscar.apps.voucher.apps.VoucherConfig',
    'oscar.apps.wishlists.apps.WishlistsConfig',
    'oscar.apps.dashboard.apps.DashboardConfig',
    'oscar.apps.dashboard.reports.apps.ReportsDashboardConfig',
    'oscar.apps.dashboard.users.apps.UsersDashboardConfig',
    'oscar.apps.dashboard.orders.apps.OrdersDashboardConfig',
    'oscar.apps.dashboard.catalogue.apps.CatalogueDashboardConfig',
    'oscar.apps.dashboard.offers.apps.OffersDashboardConfig',
    'oscar.apps.dashboard.partners.apps.PartnersDashboardConfig',
    'oscar.apps.dashboard.pages.apps.PagesDashboardConfig',
    'oscar.apps.dashboard.ranges.apps.RangesDashboardConfig',
    'oscar.apps.dashboard.reviews.apps.ReviewsDashboardConfig',
    'oscar.apps.dashboard.vouchers.apps.VouchersDashboardConfig',
    'oscar.apps.dashboard.communications.apps.CommunicationsDashboardConfig',
    'oscar.apps.dashboard.shipping.apps.ShippingDashboardConfig',

    # 3rd-party apps that oscar depends on
    'widget_tweaks',
    'haystack',
    'treebeard',
    'sorl.thumbnail',   # Default thumbnail backend, can be replaced
    'django_tables2',
]

SITE_ID = 1

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    
    'oscar.apps.basket.middleware.BasketMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.flatpages.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'frobshop.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'oscar.apps.search.context_processors.search_form',
                'oscar.apps.checkout.context_processors.checkout',
                'oscar.apps.communication.notifications.context_processors.notifications',
                'oscar.core.context_processors.metadata',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'frobshop.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'db.sqlite3',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
        'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True,
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'oscar.apps.customer.auth_backends.EmailBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.simple_backend.SimpleEngine',
    },
}


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

## url.py

```
"""frobshop URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.apps import apps
from django.urls import include, path
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    path('i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),

    # The Django admin is not officially supported; expect breakage.
    # Nonetheless, it's often useful for debugging.

    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

    path('', include(apps.get_app_config('oscar').urls[0])),
]
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to define a `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL` in `setting.py` and add a mapping for media in `urls.py`. So your `urls.py` file should look like the following:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.apps import apps
from django.urls import include, path
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    path('i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),

    # The Django admin is not officially supported; expect breakage.
    # Nonetheless, it's often useful for debugging.

    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

    path('', include(apps.get_app_config('oscar').urls[0])),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

`MEDIA_ROOT` can be like the following:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = location("public/media")
```

Please remember, you should not use this in production. In production you should use a static file server to serve the media and static files. Check the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development) for more information.